# Checkbox not reflecting changes in the state in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, state

I cannot get my reactjs component to reflect the actual changes in state on a checkbox. Could anyone kindly assist or point out what is wrong with my code below.

This is my state

```
 state = {
    data: {
      name: "",
      address: "",
      city: "",
      country: "",
      mobile_number: "",
      description: "",
      has_conference: false,
      star_rating: "",
    },
    errors: {},
  };
```

This handle checkbox method

```
toggleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      has_conference: !this.state.data["has_conference"],
    });
  };
```

And finally the checkbox code in render method

```
                <label>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  has_conference={this.state.data["has_conference"]}
                  onChange={this.toggleChange}
                />
                Conferencing
              </label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to correct in your code.

1: In toggleChange you dont change this.state.data.has_conference, but you change this.state.has_conference which is not exists in initial state. For changing this.state.data.has_conference you need to do following in your toggleChange function:

```
let data = this.state.data
data.has_conference = !data.has_conference
this.setState({data})
```

2: In  you need to bind your this.state.data.has_conference value to the checked attribute. In code you need to write:

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.toggleChange} checked={this.state.data.has_conference}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: You have really helped me a bunch. i really struggled for hours trying to make this work. Thanks alot